# How should I handle multiple publishers on the same port on the same host?

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I am using the `cluster` module and in each of the worker processes I need to publish certain values out to a single server, which subscribes to each worker.

I am using the zmq `PUB` socket in each worker process, but when each worker socket binds on the same port it causes a conflict and doesn't work. What socket pattern should I use so that I can publish/push/send values from my worker processes and subscribe to them with my server process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the pub-sub bind-connect. Sub binds and Pub connects solves the problem.

Comment: That falls over if you need more than one subscriber, which is a fairly common case. You can use the `xpub` and `xsub` sockets to build a proxy which will handle the more general n to n case.

Comment: Thanks David will have a look at it but my use-case is only a single sub.